# Dual boot wont work - installs UEIF on MBR-style partition table

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, mbr

I'm new to Linux, exciting and impressed, though not with problems, which obviously is expected with any tech and software.
However, my limited knowledge of linux and the fact that I'm not very techie has brought me here.

I have an old Dell XPS 15 502x. Not knowing much about Linux, I came across a few distros and slowly learnt what the differences are all about. Manjaro was the last one I came across before discovering Ubuntu. Manjaro did install well and run pretty good, but it wasn't long until I realized its best for "tinkering" as they say and not as stable as Ubuntu. Thus I wanted to install Ubuntu as my main OS to do my main normal daily work and have Manjaro as an alternative dual boot to tinker and learn more about Linux.

So after having Manjaro installed for a few days, I downloaded and installed Ubuntu, chose the "side by side" dual boot option.
But a problem occured in dual booting .

The GRUB menu appeared from Ubuntu with option for both OS. Ubuntu worked and booted in successfully, but Manjaro faced a black screen with basic text saying boot error.

What I've discovered is that my old system has a MBR-style partition table, so Manjaro typically installed MBR on the system. But Ubuntu has somehow installed a EIF on the system, which from what I've learnt is supposed to be done on an GDR style partition table.

Unfortunately, my BIOS does not allow to configure boot option to choose UEIF only and ignore BIOS option, so it seems I'm stuck with MBR. So the question is how do I get a dual boot with both Ubuntu and Manjaro working?

And yes I have been on the Manjaro forum and this is how I learned all this so far. The thing is, for me to be able to use Ubuntu, I need to be able to have it installed as my disc partition table desires it.

I need to have both OS running so I can use the stable Ubuntu and be able to learn on Manjaro the "tinkering" part.

[image: screenshot of my disc setup]